Radiation due to charge particles
We know that accelerated charged particles emits em waves/energy.When we apply voltage across a conductor the electric field applies force on the electrons then why don't the electrons in the conductor emit em waves/energy?

The electrical wires in your building happily emit 50/60 Hz noise.

What does 50 Hz noise mean ?

A 50/60 Hz (frequency depends on where you are) EM field, aka very low frequency radio wave. Usually shows up as unwanted noise on precision measurements.

"Frequency depends on where you are" I think frequency depends on the source.

Well, yes, the point is that different parts of the world have standardized on on or the other. What frequency your ac mains are depends on where you live. The USA is 60Hz, Europe is 50Hz (different voltages between the two).

Okay ,I got confused by where you are means at what distance you are from the wire.

Edison even made wires emit light waves!

In a DC circuit the drift velocity of the electrons is constant so they do not accelerate and therefore do not radiate.
However in an AC circuit the electrons are continuously accelerated as the AC voltage changes and they do indeed emit EM radiation. This is the 50/60Hz noise referred to in a comment.
